# Redshift: how to remove all newline characters in a field

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am wondering how I can remove all newline characters in Redshift from a field. I tried something like this:

```
replace(replace(body, '\n', ' '), '\r', ' ')
```

and

```
regexp_replace(body, '[\n\r]+', ' ')
```

But it didn't work. Please share if you know how to do this.

Comment: try `replace(body, chr(10), ' ')`  here using `chr(10)` string function instead of `\n`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `chr(10)` instead of `\n`

example:

```
select replace(CONCAT('Text 1' , chr(10), 'Text 2'), chr(10), '-') as txt
```

Comment: If, like me, you're looking for other characters, here's what I've found:
9: tab
10: new line
32: space
48-57: numbers
33-47, 58+: characters that are easily discoverable

Answer (score 7):

This should help

`regexp_replace(column, '\r|\n', '')`

Answer (score 1):

## To remove line breaks:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE('This line has
a line break', CHR(10), '');
```

This gives output: `This line hasa line break`. You can see more ASCII or `CHR()` codes here: https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/ascii-codes/

## To remove special characters like \r, \n, \t

Assuming `col1` has text like `This line has\r\n special characters`.

**Using `replace()`**

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, '\\r', ''), '\\n', '');
```

We need to escape `\` because backslash is special character in SQL (used to escape double quotes, etc...)

**Using `regexp_replace()`**

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '(\\\\r|\\\\n)', '');
```

We need to escape `\` because it is a special character in SQL and we need to escape the resulting backslashes again because backslash is a special character in regex as well.

Both `replace()` and `regexp_replace()` gives output: `This line has special characters`.

Comment: This does not work with the double escapes. Backslash is not a special character in regex. It is the escape character. 

Your line should be:

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '(\\r|\\n)', '');

Comment: You are probably right. May be my SQL editor treats backslash as a special character, thats why needed to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

I found `REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '')` to work for me. In this case, the regex pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` matches any character that is not a letter, a digit, or a space. It will remove all special characters from the string, leaving only letters, digits, and spaces.

See the documentation for other patterns you can try using the regex that is supported by AWS Redshift: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html.